# Converting Hex String element in a list to a Hex number or Hex int using python

Tags: python

```
skip = 2

with open("text.txt") as f:

    for line in f:

        if line.startswith("blah"):

            next(f)

            lst = [next(f) for i in range(skip)]
            lst = [el.replace('\n', '') for el in lst]
            for i in range(len(lst)/2):
                lst.insert(i,lst.pop(i) + lst.pop(i))
                lst =[int(i,16) for i in lst]
                print lst
```

i got:

```
lst =[int(i,16) for i in lst]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98 00 87 00 8a 00 98 00 8f 00 ca 01 78 03 54 05 bf'
```

any idea how to get a int hex?

Comment: so you find a line that starts with blah ... you skip a line and then you grab the next two lines? with each line being a list of hex ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Users will be more willing and able to help if you show us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that gets the error, including input, expected & actual output, and any warning or error messages (including compiler warnings). Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and put yourself in the place of your readers. Have you included enough information? Is it clear what you're asking?

Comment: Can you perhaps show some example input to your code and expected output? It's not at all clear what your logic is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst =[int(val,16) for line in lst for val in line.split()]
```

I think will do what you want ... although its hard to tell for sure